# Regex not returning full result

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a regex, which tries to match href attribute in HTML. Href is between a script tag and in a function. I have the correct regex I think, but the result is not complete, it is cut in half.

I have tried the regex on multiple Python Regex testing sites and all give the correct result, but when tried in my own script, it gives an unfinished result.

```py
def gotoDownload(link):
    try:
        with requests.Session().get(link) as download:
            if isUrlOnline(download):
                soup = BeautifulSoup(download.content, 'html.parser')
                filtered = soup.find_all('script')
                print(re.search(r"\'http[\s=[\s\"\']*(.*?)[\"\']*.*?\'", filtered[17].text))
```

The expected result of a link should be:
'http://mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=UkhBMmVHczFaRXA2Uld4ek1qYzVWME5DYzNodVFUMDlPampsTkQ5aFNpVWxQamVlZ3REQkpEdz0%3D'

But the output is:
match="'http://mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=UkhBM

It is cut in half, ends after the =UkhBM for some reason.

Comment: Have you tested to make sure `filtered[17].text` is returning the correct text?

Comment: Yes I have, it is returning the correct text.

Comment: It is next to a typo: `re.search(pattern, string).group()` or `.group(1)`, depending on which value you need to access, the whole match or Group 1 (if you defined it).

Comment: That also works! Thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to just get any URLs that has `'http'`, we would be just starting with a simple expression, such as:

```
('http.*?')
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RSJ5P9/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"('http.*?')"

test_str = ("'http://mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=UkhBMmVHczFaRXA2Uld4ek1qYzVWME5DYzNodVFUMDlPampsTkQ5aFNpVWxQamVlZ3REQkpEdz0%3D'\n"
    "'https://mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=UkhBMmVHczFaRXA2Uld4ek1qYzVWME5DYzNodVFUMDlPampsTkQ5aFNpVWxQamVlZ3REQkpEdz0%3D'\n"
    "'http://www.mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=UkhBMmVHczFaRXA2Uld4ek1qYzVWME5DYzNodVFUMDlPampsTkQ5aFNpVWxQamVlZ3REQkpEdz0%3D'\n"
    "'https://www.mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=UkhBMmVHczFaRXA2Uld4ek1qYzVWME5DYzNodVFUMDlPampsTkQ5aFNpVWxQamVlZ3REQkpEdz0%3D'")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I went the complicated way for regex, but the return is still
match="'http://mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=VEZCa
instead of the full length, when ran on my code :/

Comment: Yeah, I updated it https://regex101.com/r/RSJ5P9/2 it shows correctly there, but not in my own code

Answer (score 0):

For some reason changing

```
re.match(r"('http.*?')", filtered[17].text
```

to

```
re.findall(r"('http.*?')", filtered[17].text
```

works :-O